# Disable password login in console and SSH allowing only key-based login. User should be able to elevate

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication

I have debian running on virtualbox. There is only 2 users: root and user.

I want to completely turn off password based authentication in console and via ssh for both root and user.

I want user to be able to login with private key and be able to either elevate to root or to run sudo.

To turn off ssh I do

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
```

But that still leaves console-based login working. 
And inserting invalid hash in /etc/shadow, or setting /usr/sbin/nologin in /etc/passwd for both users disables sudo and su.

Comment: Try disabling `getty` (the program that ask for the login on the console), for example via systemd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable automatic spawning of virtual terminals, set the following in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
NAutoVTs=0
ReserveVT=0
```

`getty@tty1.service` probably starts by default, so disable it:

```
systemctl disable getty@tty1.service
```

I think you need to restart `systemd-logind.service`:

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

and manually stop any existing `getty@ttyN.service`:

```
systemctl stop "getty@tty*.service"
```

This may not terminate all processes using ttys, so you may want to examine the output of `ps` to find processes having `/dev/tty*` as their controlling terminals and deal with them. The `-t` option of `ps` may be helpful.

Or just reboot.

---

The relevant fragment of [`man 5 logind.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html):

> `NAutoVTs=`
> Takes a positive integer. Configures how many virtual terminals (VTs) to allocate by default that, when switched to and are previously unused, "autovt" services are automatically spawned on. These services are instantiated from the template unit `autovt@.service` for the respective VT TTY name, for example, `autovt@tty4.service`. By default, `autovt@.service` is linked to `getty@.service`. In other words, login prompts are started dynamically as the user switches to unused virtual terminals. Hence, this parameter controls how many login "gettys" are available on the VTs. If a VT is already used by some other subsystem (for example, a graphical login), this kind of activation will not be attempted. Note that the VT configured in `ReserveVT=` is always subject to this kind of activation, even if it is not one of the VTs configured with the `NAutoVTs=` directive. Defaults to `6`. When set to `0`, automatic spawning of "autovt" services is disabled.
>
> `ReserveVT=`
> Takes a positive integer. Identifies one virtual terminal that shall unconditionally be reserved for `autovt@.service` activation (see above). The VT selected with this option will be marked busy unconditionally, so that no other subsystem will allocate it. This functionality is useful to ensure that, regardless of how many VTs are allocated by other subsystems, one login "getty" is always available. Defaults to `6` (in other words, there will always be a "getty" available on Alt-F6.). When set to `0`, VT reservation is disabled.